# Powershell - amend date format to values in CSV column

Tags: mysql, date, powershell, csv, format

I'm looking for a PowerShell script for the following ...

I have a CSV spread sheet which automatically downloads from a website, the 2nd column of the spread sheet is a date value in the UK format dd/mm/yyyy. I'd like a script that will change the date format of all values in column 2 to the US date format yyyy/mm/dd.

I'm importing the CSV into a MySQL database using LOAD DATA INFILE and at present the dates are going in 2017/02/15 when they should be 2015/02/17.

An example of the CSV file format is as follows ...

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Value1,17/02/15,Value3,Value4
Value1,18/02/15,Value3,Value4
Value1,19/02/15,Value3,Value4
```

I need it to become ...

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
Value1,2015-02-17,Value3,Value4
Value1,2015-02-18,Value3,Value4
Value1,2015-02-19,Value3,Value4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way could be (will replace all date in UK format to US format, regardless of the column):

```
(get-content c:\file.csv) -replace "(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})", '$3/$2/$1'
```

if you want to save the result pipe to set-content :

```
(get-content c:\file.csv) -replace "(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})", '$3/$2/$1'  |sc c:\file.csv
```

Comment: I tried running the script against the CSV, it appears to run but doesn't change the date format - the CSV still shows the date as 17/02/15 as apposed to 2015-02-17.

Comment: did you save the file using set-content ?

Comment: Yes - I've copied your code from the 2nd example and tried it with 'set-content' also. It saves the file to a new CSV but has no change to the date format.

Comment: Having reviewed your post - I believe I stumbled across this possible 'way' in another post but all it seemed to do then was change the date to the following 17/02/2015 - hence 2 2 4, rather than actually reverse the year and day values.

Comment: please update your question and put some lines of your csv please, this is working on my win7 x64....

Comment: I've updated the question with an example of the CSV file. I'm running this on Windows 2003 x86 using PS version 2.0.

Comment: hey in your exemple the format is `dd/mm/yy` not `dd/mm/yyyy`. So modify the regex to this : `"(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})"`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can convert many formats and you can find invalid values.

Example:

```
$dateString = "17/02/2015"

$format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
[ref]$parsedDate = get-date
$parsed = [DateTime]::TryParseExact($dateString, $format,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,[System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,$parseddate)

$parsedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Comment: This code is .NET - I'm looking for something in PowerShell ideally.

Comment: @james If that is a requirement you need to put that in the question. This is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: I agree the answer is good, the title starts 'Powershell' - apologies if I have not made it more clear.

Comment: @james this is powershell. You can call all .net methods inside powershell. I tested in powershell ise. Just run this code and you'll see.